# Curving path using curved profile

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

I'm trying to re-create an object using different curves and different paths

Example object should look something like this:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/n9Odf1y.png]

My thought was creating each half separately and joining them together, since the curves and profiles on each side are different.

I created my path along with the profile I want.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/SrPoUtb.png]

But it doesn't look anything like the left half of the object I'm trying to get

[image: https://i.imgur.com/4V0bByl.png]

Should I be using a different technique?

I've attached the blend file.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curve will make Y "up":

[image]

Make sure the wanted top part of the bevel object is oriented to Y with no rotation in object mode.

In your original file, the curve as no width because the bevel object has no size in Y. So all its vertices are along the curve.